# PostGIS queries result in "Symbol not found: __ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv"

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, mac, sfcgal

> I seem to have lost the ability to use basic postgis queries. Normal postgres queries are unaffected.

Using Mac (High Sierra), using postgres 10.5 / postgis 2.4 (probably)

The same error happens accessing from QGIS, Postico, pgAdmin4, psql and using the Node.js pg library.

This seems to be a fairly new development - I successfully ran similar queries in Node about a week ago. I have no idea what's changed since then. I find it odd that the errors are related to SFCGAL as I don't recall ever installing this.

> PostgreSQL said: could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.4.so": dlopen(/usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.4.so, 10): Symbol not found: __ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/sfcgal/lib/libSFCGAL.1.dylib
>     Expected in: /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib
>    in /usr/local/opt/sfcgal/lib/libSFCGAL.1.dylib

I tend to install using Homebrew. Has anyone got a solution?

I suppose I can always set up a Docker container and use that, but I have a lot of databases that I'd rather not lose!